# Runtime Error 438 message determining LastRow

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I get

> Runtime Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

on the "LastRow" line.

I am trying to set up multiple Outlook tasks (reminders to update certificates) based on data located in an Excel worksheet. Each row includes the data required to set up each task for each certificate.

I need to determine the last row with data.

Entire code.

```vb
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olTask As TaskItem
    
    Dim wsMEDCMain As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowNumber As Long
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    
    With wsMain
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").EndofUp.Row '<-------  Line with error
        
        If 2 > LastRow Then Exit Sub
        For RowNumber = 2 To LastRow
            If Len(Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value) > 0 Then
            
                'Create Task Item
                Set olTask = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
                With olTask
                    .Subject = Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value
                    .Status = olTaskNotStarted
                    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                    .StartDate = Cells(RowNumber, "B").Value
                    .DueDate = Cells(RowNumber, "A").Value
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderTime = .StartDate & (" 09:00:00")
                    .Body = Cells(RowNumber, "D").Value & vbNewLine & ("Certificate Details: ") & Cells(RowNumber, ("C")).Value
                    .Save
                End With
            
                'Clear Object Variable
                Set olTask = Nothing
            End If
        Next RowNumber
    
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: You're uwing `With wsMain`, but then never actually "link" any ranges to it. Included in @DarrenBartrup-Cook's answer, is linking `Cells()` to the `wsMain`. However, later in the loop you have another unqualified `Cells()`, make sure to link that back to the `With` statement if you expect that to be on `wsMain`.

Comment: Hi Thanks Darren, I have come up to the same solution on my own in the end,... but thank you!! 
I now have another problem,... The macro works when I repeatedly hit F8 key but it doesn't work when I hit the commandbutton which contains the code.... Mind boggling!

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne also I have also removed the With wsMain and added wsMain. everywhere where it was required. Not sure how how I worked that one out,... I guess certain things are starting to make sense slowly but surely!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `EndofUp` with `End(xlUp)` an that should fix it for you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few modification you should make to your code, some already listed by @Darren Bartrup-Cook

1. Looking for Last row:

Change:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").EndofUp.Row
```

With:

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

2. Looking at `Len` of a cell, also not fully qualified with `wsMain` worksheet object.

Change:

```
If Len(Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value) > 0 Then
```

With:

```
If Len(.Range("C" & RowNumber).Value) > 0 Then
```

3. Avoid using a `With` statement, inside another `With`.

This line:

```
With olTask  ' <-- Setting a With inside another With statement
```

is inside:

```
With wsMain
```